# rails 3 mongoid and countries gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, mongoid, country-codes

I'd like to use the countries gem I found here instead creating a separate model.

It works fine to inherit from but I'd also like to be able to have other classes belong_to it.

Is this possible?  IE something like below.  Is there some method I could use to provide a key to child classes?

https://github.com/hexorx/countries

```
class Country < ISO3166::Country
  #include Mongoid::Document    

  #RELATIONS
  has_many :cities
  has_many :reviews, as: :reviewable
end
```

At the moment I get NoMethodError: undefined method `has_many' for Country:Class

Or some way to include/inherit the attributes from the gem after the object is initialized?

```
class Country# < ISO3166::Country
  include Mongoid::Document

  #field :name, :type => String
  field :country_id, :type => String

  ##RELATIONS
  has_many :cities
  has_many :reviews, as: :reviewable


  def after_initialize
    ISO3166::Country.find_country_by_alpha3(self.country_id)
  end


end
```

Answer (score 0):

To me the best behavior is not using `has_many` in your case but create method you want with Mongoid query inside.